# Data Factory copy from Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The Copy activity does not support Azure Cognitive Search as a source.  Sink is fine but not a source.  Makes transferring indexed documents from one index to another tedious: an until around get + post batches to the Search API with conditional variables to break the outer until iteration.

Easier way?

Answer (score 0):

As of now Azure cognitive search is not supported as source. Azure cognitive search can be used as Sink only in Azure data factory copy activity. Refer the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview) for supported data stores

[image]